# HttpServletRequest.getServletPath is returning decoded string

Tags: spring, url, servlets

On my site I'm using the following URL: http://example.com/test%2Ftest2.htm
When I print getServletPath in my HandlerInterceptorAdapter I see de decoded servletPath: `/test/test2.htm`. How do I get the not-decoded string? Like: `/test/test2&2Ftest2.htm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution, the key is to make a new URL object.

```
URL url = new URL(request.getServletPath());
String path = url.getPath();
```

This returns the desired non-decoded string.

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpServletRequest`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

> getRequestURL() - Reconstructs the URL the client used to make the request.
>
> getQueryString() - Returns the query string that is contained in the request URL after the path.

Combining the results of getRequestURL() and getQueryString() should get you the desired result.
E.g.

```
String fullURL = request.getRequestURL().append("?").append( 
     request.getQueryString()).toString();


public static String getUrl(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String reqUrl = req.getRequestURL().toString();
    String queryString = req.getQueryString();   // d=789
    if (queryString != null) {
        reqUrl += "?"+queryString;
    }
    return reqUrl;
}
```

or

```
public static String getURL(HttpServletRequest req) {

    String scheme = req.getScheme();             // http
    String serverName = req.getServerName();     // hostname.com
    int serverPort = req.getServerPort();        // 80
    String contextPath = req.getContextPath();   // /mywebapp
    String servletPath = req.getServletPath();   // /servlet/MyServlet
    String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();         // /a/b;c=123
    String queryString = req.getQueryString();          // d=789

    // Reconstruct original requesting URL
    StringBuffer url =  new StringBuffer();
    url.append(scheme).append("://").append(serverName);

    if ((serverPort != 80) && (serverPort != 443)) {
        url.append(":").append(serverPort);
    }

    url.append(contextPath).append(servletPath);

    if (pathInfo != null) {
        url.append(pathInfo);
    }
    if (queryString != null) {
        url.append("?").append(queryString);
    }
    return url.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a URL, %2F is exactly equivalent to "/". So this is translated automatically for you, and I don't think you can tell whether this was done.

This type of hex encoding is normally used for characters that are not allowable as URL characters (e.g. space is often encoded as %20) but you can replace any character with its hex code in this manner.

This technique is also used for passing characters that have special meaning within the URL syntax, within parameter names/values. E.g. '?' and '&' are used to *separate* parameters, so these need to be encoded to accurately pass them as data to the server if they are used *within* a form/parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
URI uri = new URI(null, null, request.getServletPath(), null);
String encodedServletPath = uri.toString();
```

See also:
https://zscribble.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/urlencoder-is-not-for-url-encoding-really/